# How to exclude a taxonomy from shop & search page wooCommerce?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, hooks, tax-query

In my wooCommerce shop, I've 2 taxonomy

**1. Product Category

2. Services Category**

**Shop** page is showing up all products from both categories. I want to exclude products from SHOP & Search Results page which are in the **Services Category**.

Is this thing car be achieved by pre_get_posts ? but I think it will not on work with the wooCommerce shop page.

Let me know what is the best approach to do this. any hooks or actions for this.

Thank you.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you with Shop page listing:

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/exclude-a-category-from-the-shop-page/

And for Search page, here is a snippet that might help:

```
function exclude_services_category_products_from_search( $query ) {

   if ( is_search() && !is_admin() ) {

        $array_with_service_category_id = [];
        $tax_query = $query->get( 'tax_query' ) ?: [];

        $tax_query[] = [
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'terms' => $array_with_service_category_id,
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        ];
    
        $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
    
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_services_category_products_from_search' );
```

Just add the **Service Category** id in the $array_with_service_category_id array.